# Vale a pena fazer exercícios que ensinam maneiras não muito otimizadas de fazer um programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom, eu estou aprendendo python e as vezes me deparo com alguns exercícios relativamente difíceis, por exemplo, um exercício onde o programa tinha de ler um valor em dinheiro e dizer em quantas notas de 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 aquele dinheiro poderia ser representado.

O problema é que só poderiam ser usadas estruturas condicionais e operadores matemáticos.

## Dúvida

Vale a pena fazer esse tipo de exercício e aprender a fazer um código que poderia ser simplificado ?

Qual o objetivo desse tipo de exercício ?

Comment: Testar seu pensamento lógico. Fazer um código que dê o resultado esperado não é, necessariamente, fazer um bom código. O ideal é resolver o mesmo exercício das mais diversas formas que conseguir e compará-las, entendo as diferenças e as principais características de cada uma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, se você já entende como ficaria o código assim, e consegue imagina-lo na sua mente, não precisa fazer não.  Em particular, se não puder usar estruturas de laço, eu recomendo não fazer - artificial demais, e inútil demais (não vai ter como resolver de forma genérica, para qualquer valor). Em vez disso, pegue exercícios mais desafiadores

O objetivo é só ter certeza que quem está aprendendo a programar pela primeira vez entenda bem condicionais - se você já entendeu, não tem por que ficar seguindo essas restrições: qualquer problema real que você pegar vai exercitar o uso de condicionais também.

Um lugar que tem uns probleminhas legais é o [project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) - todos os problemas são de natureza numérica, e a resposta é um único número, mas quase todos exigem que você crie um programa pra chegar na resposta - e não interessa pra eles como você fez o programa ou em que linguagem,só o número da resposta. Os exercícios vão ficando gradualmente mais difíceis, e logo fica natural que ou você faz com o algoritmo mais eficiente, ou o seu programa iria ficar uns dois anos rodando.